# Replace 'Attribute' with custom field (post-meta) value in a script that is working ( Woocommerce )

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, post-meta

This should be fairly straight forward but I keep getting "Internal Server Error" when trying to swap the custom field value with the attribute value.

Below I have 2 workings functions...

1. **The first is a function that adds a custom field into a variable product** *(and displays its value/info on the front-end).*
2. **The second subtracts an amount from the overall stock of a Variable Product using the numeric value of an attribute.**

**

## I would like to use the numeric value from my custom field rather than that of the attribute.

**

```
// -----------------------------------------
// 1. Add custom field input @ Product Data > Variations > Single Variation

add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'bbloomer_add_custom_field_to_variations', 10, 3 );

function bbloomer_add_custom_field_to_variations( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
'id' => 'custom_field[' . $loop . ']',
'class' => 'short',
'label' => __( 'Amount of Product', 'woocommerce' ),
'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'custom_field', true )
)
);
}

// -----------------------------------------
// 2. Save custom field on product variation save

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'bbloomer_save_custom_field_variations', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_save_custom_field_variations( $variation_id, $i ) {
$custom_field = $_POST['custom_field'][$i];
if ( isset( $custom_field ) ) update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'custom_field', esc_attr( $custom_field ) );
}

// -----------------------------------------
// 3. Store custom field value into variation data

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'bbloomer_add_custom_field_variation_data' );

function bbloomer_add_custom_field_variation_data( $variations ) {
$variations['custom_field'] = '<div class="woocommerce_custom_field">Amount: <span class="weight">' . get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'custom_field', true ) . '</span></div>';
return $variations;
}
```

**BELOW IS THE SCRIPT TO DEDUCT THE AMOUNTS BASED ON THE ATTRIBUTE**

```
// reduce stock based on 'pa_weight' attribute
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', 'filter_order_item_quantity', 10, 3 ); 
function filter_order_item_quantity( $quantity, $order, $item )  
{
    $product   = $item->get_product();
    $term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_weight');

    // 'pa_weight' attribute value is "15 grams" - keep only the numbers
    $quantity_grams = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term_name);

    // new quantity
    if( is_numeric ( $quantity_grams ) && $quantity_grams != 0 )
        $quantity *= $quantity_grams;

    return $quantity;
}

// check out of stock using 'pa_weight' attribute
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_validate_attribute_weight' );
function woocommerce_validate_attribute_weight() 
{
    // get product id
    if (isset($_REQUEST["add-to-cart"])) {
        $productid = (int)$_REQUEST["add-to-cart"];
    } else {
        $productid = null;
    }

    // get quantity
    if (isset($_REQUEST["quantity"])) {
        $quantity = (int)$_REQUEST["quantity"];
    } else {
        $quantity = 1;
    }

    // get weight of selected attribute
    if (isset($_REQUEST["attribute_pa_weight"])) {
        $weight = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $_REQUEST["attribute_pa_weight"]);
    } else {
        $weight = null;
    }

    // comparing stock
    if($productid && $weight)
    {
        $product = wc_get_product($productid);
        $productstock = (int)$product->get_stock_quantity();

        if(($weight * $quantity) > $productstock)
        {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'You cannot add that amount of "%1$s" to the cart because there is not enough stock (%2$s remaining).', $product->get_title(), $productstock ), 'error' );
            return;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have tried replacing :

```
$term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_weight');
```

With :

```
$term_name = $product->get_post_meta('custom_field');
```

This hasn't worked... Not sure where the issue is.

Comment: If you get internal server error, did you try to check out the php log? Or you may consider adding this line to your config: `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/volumes/some_place/wp-errors.log' );` You can read the error inside which should have explained what is happening.

Comment: @simongcc it turns out it is 'PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object' - not sure how to fix that.